# Intel driver has crashed and recovered: Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a republic of gamers brand laptop. It came with Intel 4600 intergrated video card and Nvidia gtx 960m.

The weird part about it is that the error message say it is a "window 8 driver for intel". The laptop originally came with window 8 but upgrade straight to windows 10 last summer.

The problem although I tried to keep Nvidia update and it works fine.

Whenever the Intel card crash the screen goes blank from stuff like Youtube video website and other light load at randomly.

I tried to update the Intel card but ran into some issues 6 to 8 months ago. It was not a big issue but I notice it has been happening slightly more often now.

I am wondering how would I keep the Intel card driver up, as part of dual-video card setup, to date safely?

Comment: run this tool: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24345/Intel-Driver-Update-Utility

Comment: Look like I already had that tool on my laptop as recently as Jaunary third. So I just update my intel tool. I don't see any option to update my drivers.

Comment: Intel has Windows 10 drivers for that iGPU on their website.  What drives are you downloading from Intel specifically that say "Windows 8"

Comment: As far I can determine the intel driver is 10.18.15.4256 and dated July 2015 which came with the default drivers shipped on the laptop. It is not one I put there per se. The model number for laptop is GL551JW-DS71.

Comment: Why is there a downvote? The laptop comes with the outdate driver and intel update utility refuse to update the driver. I am pretty much stuck in middle of a lake without a paddle with respect to updating my intel card drivers.

Comment: the 4300 seams to be the latest driver: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25489/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-10-15-40-4th-Gen- try this driver

Comment: Oh fun. I think we may have to manually install the driver because. The exe after run once, comes up with an error. "The driver being installed is not validated for this computer. Please obtain the appropriate driver from the computer manufacturer. Setup will exit.". The only option present is to take me to intel support website or not...

Comment: extract the 4300 driver with 7zip and use device manager to update the driver: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9695-driver-install-device-manager-windows-8-a.html

Comment: Apparently they also check if you have an unique manufacturer driver via device manager's upgrade driver. After I click to search driver in a folder. It comes up with a message saying "Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date". The ironic part is that my gtx 960 just got update the other day no hassle via nvidia experience.

Comment: click on "let me pick a list of devices", next click on " have disk" and select here the inf file from the driver

Comment: That "pick a list of devices" method comes up with an error after picking the inf file. "The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems." The silly part is it is the MOST recent 64x driver for a 64x intel video card. Oh well thank all for trying to help me out.